# Derivative of Inverse Linear Transformation

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am going through Sagle and Walde's Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras and am in the first chapter reviewing (advanced) calculus. I am mostly OK with the advanced calculus stuff, I have been through most of Widder and some of Spivak. There is an exercise in the differentiation section I don't quite get:

> Show the map
> $$
> f: GL(V) \rightarrow GL(V) : T \rightarrow T^{-1}
> $$
> is differentiable at P and
> $$
> Df(P)T = -P^{-1}TP^{-1}.
> $$
> Thus show $f\in C^{1}(GL(V),End(V))$

I understand the question, however, I don't see how we can end up with a $P^{-1}$ multiplied on both sides. If I say:

$$
\begin{align}
f(P)&=P^{-1} \\
Pf(P)&=I \\
f(P) + PDf(P) &= 0 \\
PDf(P) &= -f(P) \\
PDf(P) &= -P^{-1} \\
Df(P) &= -P^{-2}
\end{align}
$$

With this derivative, we would get

$$
Df(P)T = -P^{-2}T
$$

Additonally, the derivative should be a linear transformation, and so it should have an inverse. In my case, that inverse is $P^{2}$. In the case of what the book claims, I don't see how there can be a single inverse independent of $T$.

I am guessing I am missing something because the book is Volume 51 in the Academic Press series Pure and Applied Mathematics, so I am sure a lot of good eyes were on it. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $DF_X$ denote the differential of $F$ at $X$, and $DF_X(H)$ its evaluation at $H$. We will also write $D^H_X[F(X)]$ to mean the same, the purpose of this notation being that we are differentiating "with respect to" $X$ and to remove the clutter that $(H)$ causes.

To begin, there is a fact that does not seem to be as well-known is it should be which I have taken to stating as follows:

- *The derivative of an expression is the sum of the derivatives of it's subexpressions*:
  $$
    D_X[F(X,X)] = D_{\dot X}[F(\dot X, X)] + D_{\dot X}[F(X, \dot X)].
  $$
  On the RHS, the undotted $X$ should be "held constant"; it is not differentiated. On the LHS, both $X$s are differentiated.

Going step by step, we can see what goes wrong with your argument. First we apply the subexpression rule to $PP^{-1}$:
$$
  0 = D^H_P[PP^{-1}] = D^H_{\dot P}[\dot PP^{-1}] + D^H_{\dot P}[P\dot P^{-1}].
$$
The function $Q \mapsto QP^{-1}$ is linear, so it is its own differential and we get
$$
  HP^{-1} + D^H_{\dot P}[P\dot P^{-1}].
$$
This is where you went wrong. While it is true that $D^H_{\dot P}[\dot PP^{-1}] = D^H_P[P]P^{-1}$ via the chain rule, it is *nonsensical* to write $D_P[P]P^{-1}$ since $D_P[P]$ is a *function* $H \mapsto D^H_P[P]$ and $P^{-1}$ is a matrix. It is equally nonsensical to say that $D_P[P]$ is the identity matrix, which is what you did; it is instead *the identity function on matrices*. To avoid such pitfalls, it is generally a good idea to always evaluate your differentials on something like $H$.

Continuing with our derivation, we use the chain rule on the second term to get
$$
  0 = HP^{-1} + PD^H_P[P^{-1}].
$$
It now easily follows that
$$
  D^H_P[P^{-1}] = -P^{-1}HP^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Regarding "the identity matrix... it is instead the identity function on matrices" above, I came to this conclusion last night. The two are different. I know how to differentiate sub expressions. For the rest, in $0 = D^{H}_{P}[PP^{-1}]$, are you using that the derivative of the identity matrix is 0 as your starting point? From there, you use the subexpression rule. I take $D^{H}_{\dot{P}}[]$ to mean differentiate the expression in $[]$ WRT $\dot{P}$ and then evaluate $\dot{P}$ at $H$. Why is the derivative of $\dot{P}$ WRT $\dot{P}$ the identity function, when $\frac{d}{dx}x=1$ for scalars?

Comment: I guess my last question is in reference to "It is equally nonsensical..." above. I get the difference, but for scalars, if $f(x)=x$ is the identity function, then $\frac{df}{dx}=1$, the multiplicative identity. So evaluation at $h$ is still $1$. I guess my expectation is that for functions on linear transforms, if $f(P)=P$ is the identity function, then $\frac{df}{dP}=I$, the multiplicative identity. There is a problem though, as stated, that the matrix derivative of a matrix has $n^{2} \times n^{2}$ components, so the reasoning is wrong. I think I have to daydream on this for a while.

Comment: @PoissonAerohead You are correct that I started from $1 = PP^{-1}$. But we are **not** "evaluating $\dot P$ at $H$"; this suggests to me a misunderstanding of total differentials. We take a differential *at a fixed point* $P$ ("point" meaning here "point in the space of matrices", i.e. just a matrix), and then evaluate that differential on $H$. The differential at $P$ is a linear transformations such that if $H$ is "small" then $F(P + H) = F(P) + DF_P(H) = F(P) + D^H_P[F(P)]$...

Comment: ...The reason $\dot P$ is "replaced" with $H$ in $D^H_{\dot P}[\dot PP^{-1}]$ is because $DF_P(H) = F(H)$ for any linear function $F$; if $F$ is not linear then you cannot just replace $\dot P$ with $H$, and in general the differential will depend on the value of $P$. Now, as for scalar functions, $df/dx$ **is not a differential**. The differential of a scalar function $f$ is $Df_x(h) = \frac{df}{dx}h$, which is to say that the differential is *multiplication* by $df/dx$. So indeed the differential of $f(x) = x$ is the identity function $Df_x(h) = h$.

Comment: Defining a general "matrix derivative" $dF/dP$ analogous to $df/dx$ is impossible since there need not be a matrix $M(P)$ such that $DF_P(H) = M(P)H$. The matrix derivatives that you do see around are simply special cases where this is possible.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Yeah, that all makes sense. I understand total differentials, and I understand that the derivative is a linear transform. I guess what I was overlooking is that, using your $D^{H}_{P}$ notation, which means evaluating the derivative (linear transform) at H, the evaluation in fact creates a total differential. The geometry of that feels intuitive enough. Given this, the the result works all the way down to single variable calculus, which makes more sense than it being different for transforms. Like I told Qiaochu, I'm gonna read Spivak again, or any other recommendation.

Comment: Regarding 'Defining a general "matrix derivative"...' I was starting to suspect this, as the problem is over (or under, depending on perspective) defined (you need to do the work of an $n^{2} \times n^{2}$ with an $n \times n$). Thanks, all of this is really helpful. So when you see a "matrix derivative" like $\frac{d}{dt}A(t)B(t)=A'(t)B(t)+A(t)B'(t)$, this is because for that particular function it is possible. But for general differentiation by a matrix, the situation in general requires a 4th order tensor to define fully and so there is no general matrix expression.

Comment: @PoissonAerohead Yes exactly; it works because $t$ is a scalar so the differential *has to be* a function from scalars to matrices that just multiplies scalars by a matrix, and we define that matrix as the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is incorrect; you are treating this as if it were single-variable calculus and it is not. $Df(P)$ is a linear transformation from matrices to matrices and so the third line $f(P) + P D f(P) = 0$ where you treat $D f(P)$ as if it were just a matrix is incorrect. (Edit: more elaboration on this in the comments.)

Here is a sketch of a correct argument. The derivative of $f$ at $P$, by definition, is the linear map $Df_P(T)$ (I prefer this notation to yours) which satisfies

$$f(P + \varepsilon) = (P + \varepsilon)^{-1} = P^{-1} + Df_P(\varepsilon) + O \left( \| \varepsilon \|^2 \right)$$

where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes any matrix norm and $\varepsilon$ is a matrix of small norm, thought of as a tangent vector to $P$. Now we compute that

$$\begin{eqnarray*} (P + \varepsilon)^{-1} &=& (P(I + P^{-1} \varepsilon))^{-1} \\
 &=& (I + P^{-1} \varepsilon)^{-1} P^{-1} \\
 &=& \left( I - P^{-1} \varepsilon + \left( P^{-1} \varepsilon \right)^2 \mp \dots \right) P^{-1} \\
 &=& \left( I + P^{-1} \varepsilon + O \left( \| \varepsilon \|^2 \right) \right) P^{-1} \\
 &=& P^{-1} - P^{-1} \varepsilon P^{-1} + O \left( \| \varepsilon \|^2 \right) \end{eqnarray*}$$

which gives $Df_P(\varepsilon) = - P^{-1} \varepsilon P^{-1}$ as desired. In the third line we are using a geometric series expansion and the fourth line takes a bit more work to justify but follows from the same estimate for the usual geometric series together with the submultiplicativity of any matrix norm.

The derivative is only equal to $- P^{-2} \varepsilon$ if $P$ and $\varepsilon$ commute, and its inverse is $Df_{P^{-1}}(\varepsilon) = - P \varepsilon P$.

Comment: Thanks. It is not my notation, I was just copying the book. I understand lines 3 and 4 and don't really need to see justification. As far as the first paragraph, wow, did not expect that to be it. I of course expected commuting issues, but in my argument I never commute anything. Can you point me to a product rule for linear transformations? There must be one, right?

Comment: To be clear, I understand that these are linear transformations of matrices to matrices, but those still can be written as matrices. So I thought that matrices had a product rule where you just minded the order (unlike scalar calculus where order doesn't matter). So you would have to say for matrices (AB)' = A'B + AB'. In scalar calculus, saying (AB)' = BA' + AB' is acceptable, due to commutativity. I guess this is wrong?

Comment: @Poisson: the problem is that you are not paying attention to $\varepsilon$ in your argument. Here is a correct version of line 3: starting from $P f(P) = I$ we consider varying $P$ in the direction $\varepsilon$, which gives $(P + \epsilon)(f(P) + D f_P(\epsilon)) = I$. Equating terms of order $\| \varepsilon \|$ gives $\epsilon f(P) + P D f_P(\epsilon) = 0$; this is correct and it leads to the correct result. In your argument you aren't paying attention to whether $\epsilon$ is on the left or right and also in some sense pretending that $D f_P(\epsilon)$ is a matrix (it is a tensor).

Comment: More explicitly, "matrix" here means $n \times n$ matrix. A linear transformation from matrices to matrices is a fourth-order tensor, which can be represented as an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix. It's a more complicated object whereas here your argument in some sense pretends the derivative is just left multiplication by an $n \times n$ matrix, which it isn't.

Comment: It is true that there is a "product rule for matrices" in the following sense: if $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are two matrix-valued functions of a real parameter $t$, then $\frac{d}{dt} A(t) B(t) = A'(t) B(t) + A(t) B'(t)$. But this isn't the situation we're in; we're differentiating with respect to a matrix, not a scalar, and that makes things more complicated.

Comment: Qiaochu, regarding the comments about tensor, $n^{2} \times n^{2}$ matrix, and two matrix valued functions of a scalar, yes, I fell asleep thinking through all of this last night. Thanks, I got it. I was treating $Df$ as if it were $n \times n$ in my reasoning and it is not. I have decided to spend some time on Spivak again (Calculus on Manifolds) before going forward.

Comment: Qiaochu, your answer is correct and thank you for your time. I gave the accepted answer to the other submission because he walked me through how to make the argument I was actually trying to make. This answer is interesting and helpful though.